# Mysql not retrieving full data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, special-characters, password-storage

I'm storing passwords in my Mysql database , these passwords have special characters . The passwords are storing fine but while retrieving these passwords , incomplete passwords are displayed , the password is not shown after less than sign '<'

For eg : this is the password -> abcxyz abcxyz

Comment: Umm... storing passwords is usually a really bad idea... I hope you are at the very least encrypting or hashing those passwords.

Answer (score 3):

I **assume** that you're displaying in on webiste using HTML. Then `<` is used to start a HTML tag , this is why you can't see them, but if you'll view source code then it should be there. If string contains special characters then you should escape them, e.g. with `htmlspecialchars` function.

As a side note, you shouln't store password as plain text (or display them).

Answer (score 0):

#### You should never store passwords as plain text! Never!

It is a security problem. Store a (salted) **hash** of it and you will also get rid of your problem since a hash does not contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you store special character in your database then it's not a good idea.for security reason use

```
//convert password into the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number
1) md5 — Calculate the md5 hash of a string 
2) mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.
```

this link will helpful if talk about database handling:-

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)